# I have a query that returns results but I want to delete the data inside the parenthesis like <#0077d3>

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[User code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTR9u.jpg) I used the code to display the results

```
SELECT ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.[exp] DESC)) as [rank], c.[name],c.[lv],c.[exp],
`ISNULL(b.[name],'n/a') [guild],
ISNULL(b.[icon],'none.jpg') [guild_icon],
c.[job],
CAST(
CASE
WHEN c.[login_time] > c.[logout_time]
THEN 'ON'
ELSE 'OFF'
END
AS VARCHAR ) AS [stat] FROM [Telecaster].[dbo].[Character] c
LEFT JOIN [Telecaster].[dbo].[GuildMember] a ON [sid] = a.[player_id]
LEFT JOIN [Telecaster].[dbo].[Guild] b ON b.[sid] = a.[guild_id]`
 WHERE c.[permission] < 100 AND c.[name] NOT LIKE '%@%' AND c.[lv] < 300
```

[Actual results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wY8F.jpg)

[desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Xzn.jpg)

I want to delete the color code along with the brackets

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sql Server 2008 ended all support, including security patches, over 3 years ago. Do Not Continue Using It. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/end-support-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a scalar function to remove the tags. Here's fiddle on how to do it. You could just do a STUFF in your original query but there's no error checking like you can do in a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_StripColorCode (@InputString nvarchar(512))
RETURNS nvarchar(512)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @first int = -1;
  DECLARE @last int = -1;

  --Find the start and end tags.
  SET @first = CHARINDEX('<#', @InputString, 1);
  SET @last = CHARINDEX('>', @InputString, 1);

  --If either start or end is not found, return original string.
  IF (@first < 0 OR @last < 0)
    RETURN @InputString;

  --If the start tag is found after the end tag, return the original string.
  IF (@first > @last)
    RETURN @InputString;

  --Remove the tag.
  DECLARE @result nvarchar(512);
  SET @result = STUFF(@InputString, 1, @Last, '');

  RETURN @result;
END
;
```

```
DECLARE @testName nvarchar(50) = '<#ff00c0>ASTA';
SELECT dbo.fn_StripColorCode(@testName);
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| ASTA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1sfscqE3)

Here's how I would do it inline using STUFF. I cleaned up your code a bit:

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.[exp] DESC) as [rank]
  , CASE 
      WHEN (c.[name] LIKE '<#%' AND c.[name] LIKE '%>%') 
        THEN STUFF(c.[name],1,CHARINDEX('>',c.[name]),'') 
      ELSE c.[name] 
    END [name]
  , c.[lv]
  , c.[exp]
  , ISNULL(b.[name],'n/a') [guild]
  , ISNULL(b.[icon],'none.jpg') [guild_icon]
  , c.[job]
  , CASE
      WHEN c.[login_time] > c.[logout_time]
        THEN 'ON'
      ELSE 'OFF'
    END AS [stat] 
FROM [Telecaster].[dbo].[Character] c
  LEFT JOIN [Telecaster].[dbo].[GuildMember] a 
    ON [sid] = a.[player_id]
  LEFT JOIN [Telecaster].[dbo].[Guild] b 
    ON b.[sid] = a.[guild_id]
WHERE c.[permission] < 100 
  AND c.[name] NOT LIKE '%@%' 
  AND c.[lv] < 300
```

Comment: Thank you
The last code works correctly
thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.[exp] DESC)) as [rank], CASE WHEN (c.[name] LIKE '%<%' AND c.[name] LIKE '%>%') THEN  RIGHT(c.[name],LEN(c.[name])-CHARINDEX('>',c.[name])) ELSE c.[name] END [name],c.[lv],c.[exp],
    ISNULL(b.[name],'n/a') [guild],
    ISNULL(b.[icon],'none.jpg') [guild_icon],
    c.[job],
    CAST(
    CASE
    WHEN c.[login_time] > c.[logout_time]
    THEN 'ON'
    ELSE 'OFF'
    END
    AS VARCHAR ) AS [stat] FROM [Telecaster].[dbo].[Character] c
    LEFT JOIN [Telecaster].[dbo].[GuildMember] a ON [sid] = a.[player_id]
    LEFT JOIN [Telecaster].[dbo].[Guild] b ON b.[sid] = a.[guild_id]
     WHERE c.[permission] < 100 AND c.[name] NOT LIKE '%@%' AND c.[lv] < 300
```

I assumed the color String format would be similar across the records.

Comment: Thanks for your interest my friend,
When trying to apply the code, an error occurred
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]incorrect syntax near '`'.(102)

Comment: Could you please the edited Query?